# mongodb - strategy from having relational DB CSV dump imported to highly denormalised mongodb documents

Tags: mongodb, csv, mongoimport

**We want to migrate data to mongodb using a CSV files dump created out of a teradata. Data needs to be refreshed in mongodb every night from a fresh teradata csv dump**

Approach we are thinking of is:

1. **Get the CSV files exported out of relational db**. They are going to be very similar to table structure in relational db
2. **Import the CSV files into mongodb staging collections subsequently, which will be mirroring relational db structure in terms of being normalised**. This may be done using say mongoimport in overnight batches. This is going to result in many collections as we are thinking to import each 'type' of CSV into its own collection e.g. ***Customers***.csv and ***Accounts***.csv will result in two respective collections of same name.
3. **Create de-normalised collections out of staging collections, ready to be exposed to UI.** Run some schema migration script, which queries the staging collections and creates more denormalised and fewer collections ready for use in the application UI.Eg, Customers and Accounts collections, after running migration script should result in a third collection say ***AccountCustomers*** collection where Each account doc has embedded customers array (denormalised and no need of joins when UI needs data)

   1. Question: Is there a better strategy , as all above steps are expected to complete nightly, every night?
   2. Question: Is **mongoimport** OK to use for importing the CSV files in nightly batches.
   3. Question: What is the best way to migrate (denormalise) collections within the same mongo instance?Eg we have ***stagingdb*** having collections ***customers*** and ***accounts*** and we want to reach a state where we have ***proddb*** having collection ***accountcustomers***